# Custom geddy mongodb adaptor in mongolab uri

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geddy

I want to use custom geddy adapter

```
var mongo = geddy.model.adapters.mongo.client;
    var db = mongo.db('db_name', 27017,);
    var tests = db.collection('tests');
    tests.find({}).toArray(function(err, p){
        console.log(err);
        console.log(p); 
    });
```

But I am unable to use the mongolab connection string using that module.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var mongo = geddy.model.adapters.mongo.client;
    mongo.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/db_name", function(err, db) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(db);
    });
```

you can try something like this.

Comment: Thanks , I was missing .connect